# How to find the owner of an apple app name

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an iOS app that I want to put on the app store but the app's name is taken. I can't find the name being used in an active app on the app store, so I think someone has reserved the name but hasn't published the app yet. I'm interested in buying the name from whoever has it reserved but I don't know how to go about doing this.

How do I find out who has the name reserved and how do I contact that person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply enter the desired app name and click on "save". App Store Connect will then display an error message. Click on "More" and then you can submit a copy right claim about the name. Apple will automatically contact the other app developer and if they do not respond, Apple will free up the name.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. However, at the end of the form to submit a copy right claim, it says I have to check a box to "swear under penalty of perjury that I am the owner, or agent authorized to act on behalf of the owner, of the rights that are allegedly infringed. I believe in good faith that the disputed use is not authorized by the intellectual property owner, its agent, or the law." Should I be scared off by this?

Comment: I'm no lawyer, so I cannot give you an answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

iOS app identifier can be changed any letters, and no one can see that, except the owner of the app. It's not important that you must be keeping that bundle identifier.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I didn't mean the bundle identifier name, I meant the display name of the app in the app store, the kind that users see (eg: Facebook, Instagram, WhatsApp, etc.)